# Cursor.moveToFirst() and nullpointerexception

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor

My question is: Will `moveToFirst()` throw a `NullPointerException`?

Should I use:

```
if (cursor != null) {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

or just:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: put what `cursor` has would be help

Comment: i get the `cursor` from sqlite query, which may return 0 record.

Comment: if the cursor return 0 will not error if `moveToFirst()`, but return null will be error if u call `moveToFirst`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling cursor `moveToFirst()` will not error unless your `cursor` is `null`.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using the Android [Cursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) and [SQLiteDatabase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) classes. If so then `cursor` will never be null. (So you don't have to worry about a NullPointerException here.) They can be *empty*, but `cursor.moveToFirst()` will return `false` in this case. You are safe just using:

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    // TODO
}
```

Or for more than one row:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    // TODO
}
```

Comment: yeah is my fault to return `null`